# How to initiate cores in parallel package of R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

To initiate the cluster, it is advised to use below codes

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
```

However I fail to understand what is the meaning of `getOption("cl.cores", 2)`? How exactly I can find the number of cores in my windows system to run parallel computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this is:

```r
num_cores  <- parallel::detectCores() # 8 in my case
cluster  <- parallel::makeCluster(num_cores-1)
```

Comment: why `ˇnum_cores-1`?

Comment: @BrianSmith leave one core to deal with i/o etc. or the computer will become very unresponsive.